# Why Sharepoint Timer Service is making Pc slow?

Tags: timer-jobs, timer-service

Currently Sharepoint Timer Service is stopped in my Pc and the Pc is running perfectly but when i start Sharepoint Timer Service at the time of Development, at that time it is making my Pc very slow even an effect of right click on desktop is taking 30 to 45 seconds. Can anyone know the cause of it?

Comment: could you past some line of code?

Comment: there isn't any code it is making Pc performance slow when i only start the Sharepoint Timer Service from Services.msc of Administrative Tools

Comment: sorry I mean, there aren't any custom jobs?

Comment: yes, what i m doing is only starting the Sharepoint Timer Service from Services.msc

Comment: did you check if there is some process on the job list, like "users sync"?

Comment: where can i check it?

Comment: Sharepoint central administratio -> monitor -> timer jobs status

Comment: i have checked, no user sync service is running

Comment: ok but there are other process like: crawling, taxonomy, search and process, etc etc etc